# How to find bicycle parking in Taipei?

Tags: bicycles, taiwan

I am going to Taipei with my bicycle, and plan to ride to many places for a few days. I will need to park my bicycle somewhere when I am visiting, or eating, or sleeping, etc.

The Taipei government tries to encourage its citizens to use bicycles to travel around the city, and according to [this press release](http://tcgwww.taipei.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=100923979&ctNode=9999&mp=104062) last year it released an app that helps people find bicycle parking spaces. Unfortunately, I can't find that app.

**QUESTION:** Is there a map that shows places where parking is considered OK? I have found an Android app called "TPE" that seems to show that, but it does not work offline. I need something that works with an Internet connection.

Otherwise, what local customs/manners should I know about before I park my bicycle somewhere in Taipei?

Comment: Is this the app [Taipei good parking 2.5.19 APK for Android](http://www.androidapps.biz/app/tw.pma.parkinfo) you have (or the one you want)?

Comment: @Dorothy: That app is for cars. I want the same for bicycles :-)

Comment: I didn't download, but the description does suggest that it includes motorcycle and bike parking (as well as fees). I guess there's no way to test other than download and try in Taipei :-)

Comment: @Dorothy: I downloaded it and tried it. It indeed includes a few bicycle parking places! Sadly, it does not work offline.

Comment: Take a look around Google's street view where you are going. It might be more obvious than you'd think for where you should park your bicycle ;) https://goo.gl/maps/ojRt5xytya22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've noticed during my visit earlier this year (around January), the bike\scooter\motorcycle parking is pretty straightforward in Taipei - almost every street has large spaces for leaving your transport (between the road and the pedestrian space). Security, though, is a different question - you may find some minor trouble in finding the place to chain your bike to.

Regarding the apps - you may find Maps.me quite useful as it works in offline mode, but I'm not 100% sure it's the best solution for this specific question.

Comment: Does Maps.me show bicycle parking?

Comment: It does - at least in some cities. In Taipei it simply shows you non-categorized parking spots, and it most possibly can be used for either car or a bike.